# Black Body radiation units in CGS

Tags: astronomy, thermal-radiation, units, si-units

As all of us know the equation of black body is

$$B_\nu = \frac{2 h v^3}{c^2} \times (\exp(h\nu/K_BT) - 1 ) ^{-1}$$

I know the following units $[h]$ = erg $\cdot$ sec, $[\nu]$ = Hz and $[c]$ = cm/s.

How people obtained the unit of $B_\nu$ as erg/cm$^{2}$/sec/stradian/Hz?
or even other units that is written in CGS for this quantity? Because I obtain erg/cm$^2$ or erg/(s $\cdot$ cm$^2\cdot$ Hz) that again Hz and s can be removed by each other.

Any help please?

Comment: [Gaussian, SI and Other Systems of Units](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1112/notes/emunits.pdf) and [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units).

Comment: You need to use MathJax for your equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steradians are dimensionless ratios, just like radians are, so they are often omitted. Think about angular velocity. Some people write the units for it as radians per second; others just say “per second” with the radians being understood.

Comment: Ah, so the stradian is for solid angel which we can neglect it in unit?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: and why it is written as `erg/(s ⋅ cm2⋅ Hz) `, because it is `erg/cm2`

Comment: They’re equivalent. The former corresponds more closely to the definition of $B_\nu$ as the power emitted per unit area of the body, per unit solid angle of emission, per unit frequency. The “per Hertz” makes it clear that this quantity is a spectral density.